Can ClamAV detect malicious files on a MySQL/MariaDB server?
Can ClamAV help detect malicious files (ie malware, rootkits, etc) for a MySQL/MariaDB server, specifically the /var/lib/mysql data folder?
The database server is a single role and locked down both by firewall and MariaDB user host restriction.

Are you wondering whether ClamAV will notice viruses and malware that is part of your databases, and stored in your database's native table format in that directory?

Yes, ClamAV detects malicious files by using a set of virus signatures. Although designed for e-mail scanning, it will work on any kind of Linux server, including database servers. There is no reason why it should not.
More info in the ClamAV docs.

But would it work to scan the actual databases? I would assume that the native database files would potentially be encoded and that they would therefore "hide" any malicious contents from ClamAV. I haven't made any tests to confirm this though.

It's a moot point. As long as a virus is encoded in a database table, it's not executable.

Indeed, but it could be served to a client and you may want not want that to happen. Of course, one could feed the binary data to ClamAV before writing it to the database. @Kusalananda Out of curiosity, I filled some test data in a BLOB field of an InnoDB database. The bytes are mangled (due to file format or database compression), so ClamAV cannot recognize any signature.

Well, a database contains and delivers data to users, just like a mailserver's data store does. In fact, there's nothing saying these databases don't store mail messages.

A better question would be, why are you storing files in a database?  You should store filenames in the database, not files.

One reason why it would not is if mysql has been configured to encrypt tablespaces otherwise known as encryption at rest - something the financial industry is heavy on. Unusual, but possible.
